# Conversion of strings like \\uXXXX in python

Tags: python, unicode

I receive a string like this from a third-party service:

```
>>> s
'\\u0e4f\\u032f\\u0361\\u0e4f'
```

I know that this string actually contains sequences of a single backslash, lowercase u etc. How can I convert the string such that the `'\\u0e4f'` is replaced by `'\u0e4f'` (i.e. `'๏'`), etc.? The result for this example input should be `'๏̯͡๏'`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In 2.x:

```
>>> u'\\u0e4f\\u032f\\u0361\\u0e4f'.decode('unicode-escape')
u'\u0e4f\u032f\u0361\u0e4f'
>>> print u'\\u0e4f\\u032f\\u0361\\u0e4f'.decode('unicode-escape')
๏̯͡๏
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C You are probably on Python 3 then; this is an old answer which applies to Python 2. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48908131/decodeunicode-escape-in-python-3-a-string

Answer (score 5):

There's an interesting [list of encodings](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) supported by `.encode()` and `.decode()` methods. Those magic ones in the second table include the `unicode_escape`.

Answer (score 4):

Python3:

```
bytes("\\u0e4f\\u032f\\u0361\\u0e4f", "ascii").decode("unicode-escape")
```