# mysql 5.5 utf-8 collation utf8_unicode_ci, pymysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, pymysql

I've a problem with mysql 5.5 on os x. I'm working on a multilanguages project
and using MyISAM table. the default characterset is utf-8 and default collation utf8_unicode_ci.

Italian and German are fine, but spanish is not. I'm using python for manipulating datas,
pymysql driver with charset option to utf-8 and unicode true.

Practically all the specific spanish letters are a mess.

from python shell:

```
>>>r
>>>['Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez, 4']
>>>print[0]
>>>Blas Pérez González, 4
after saving it to database and fetching it again:
>>>r
>>>(u'Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez, 4')
>>>print r[0]
>>>Blas PÃ©rez GonzÃ¡lez, 4
```

I'm really confused, it clearly seems to be the same unicode string!

Thanks.

Comment: Why first string is not preceded by 'u' (as second one?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a more detailed explanation would help me to anderstand :)

Answer (score 0):

Better use java-style unicode escapes, like

```
u'\\u0e4f\\u032f\\u0361\\u0e4f'.decode('unicode-escape')
```

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828284/conversion-of-strings-like-uxxxx-in-python).

This ensures that you have unicode in the string.

Then the actual problem: try in mysql `describe the_table`. Still in the [column definition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) one can set the character set. Try that to see if your table is okay.

---

***For testing:*** Store `u'Blas P\\u00e9rez Gonz\\u00e1lez'.decode('unicode-escape')` in the database.
Then you know that the correct unicode string is stored.
If the database has correct db/table/field definitions, only the retrieval, not storing, may be at fault.

Comment: please some more explanation. I can't encode the string in any other format until I'm able to decode the current format first.

Comment: Well, many thanks, that seems to be the problem at the least saving the string in java-style unicode and retrive it again will be displayed in the correct way: u'Blas P\xe9rez Gonz\xe1lez', without using java-style was u'Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez, 4'. My question is now how to retrive all the wrong records from the database, convert it in java-style and save it again. I'm googling since a while, unfortunately without success

Comment: what make me confused: print 'Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez, 4' it will displayed correctly, but print u'Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez, 4' not and if type unicode(u'Blas Pérez gonzález').encode('utf-8') return 'Blas P\xc3\xa9rez Gonz\xc3\xa1lez' I suppose that it isnt encoded correctly, why?

Comment: The edited/displayed character (`é`) depends on the encoding of the editor/viewer/platform. Unfortunately I have only a UTF-8 system at the moment, and no encoding experience in Python. See [u.encode](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html).