# python mixed single and double unicode escape sequences

Tags: python, unicode

I have some problems with strange escaped unicode Strings. My script consumes a webservice via the request library and response.text contains the following unicode string:

```
 u'\\u003c? abc ?\\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von \xd6kosystemen abgeleitet.\\u003c? /abc ?\\u003e'

 **Updated** Martijn solution works with the upper one, but breaks with this one because of len="12"
 u'\\u003c?abc len="12"?\\u003eResilienz sollte als st\xe4ndiger Anpassungsprozess zwischen Systemen und der Umwelt begriffen werden.\\u003c? /abc ?\\u003e'
```

The response from the server looks something like this:

```
\u003c? abc ?\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von Ökosystemen abgeleitet.\u003c?dpf /sent ?\u003e
```

The problem are the double escaped unicode sequences like \u003c, \u003c normally represents a < char. \xd6 is correct and represents a german Ö. This double escaping totally messes up my unicode string :-)

I have found a similar problem at this post:
[Stack Overflow - Conversion of strings like \uXXXX in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828284/conversion-of-strings-like-uxxxx-in-python)

The solution, using string.decode('unicode-escape'), only seems to work if all unicode sequences would be escaped but not with mixed single and double escapes. Just replacing the double escapes with single ones gives me a corrupt unicode string.

The easiest and best solution would be to adjust the response encoding on the server side, but i have no access ...

Thank's for your help!!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the content type header of those responses?

Comment: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Comment: @Martijn Pieters
I tried the the string in the firebug console, the output seems to be correct: `var a = '\u003c? abc len="12" ?\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von Ökosystemen abgeleitet.\u003c?dpf /sent ?\u003e';
console.log(a);` Strange things...

Comment: your second example, containing the extra quotes, make it invalid as a literal JSON value. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the server is returning JSON strings. JSON uses the same escape sequence, and if you add quotes around the string `json.loads()` is perfectly happy to decode that example for you:

```
>>> txt = u'\\u003c? abc ?\\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von \xd6kosystemen abgeleitet.\\u003c? /abc ?\\u003e'
>>> content = txt.encode('utf8')
>>> content
'\\u003c? abc ?\\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von \xc3\x96kosystemen abgeleitet.\\u003c? /abc ?\\u003e'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"{0}"'.format(content))
u'<? abc ?>Das Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von \xd6kosystemen abgeleitet.<? /abc ?>'
>>> print json.loads('"{0}"'.format(content))
<? abc ?>Das Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von Ökosystemen abgeleitet.<? /abc ?>
```

Try using `json.loads('"{0}"'.format(response.content))` to decode the response to Unicode.

Your updated version does contain quotes, a little vexing, since those would have to be escaped to be using in valid JSON. It probably is not JSON then, but some other form of escapes; Java and Ruby also use `\uxxxx` escapes. Next thing we can try is to use a regular expression to replace these:

```
import re

uescapes = re.compile(r'(?<!\\)\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}', re.UNICODE)
def uescape_decode(match): return match.group().decode('unicode_escape')

uescapes.sub(uescape_decode, response.text)
```

This regular expression will decode any `\uxxxx` match to it's unicode character equivalent, provided that it is not preceded by a `\`, which effectively escapes the escape; `\\uxxxx` is not going to be replaced.

The regular expression approach decodes your both examples (second decoded first):

```
>>> print uescapes.sub(uescape_decode, txt)
<?abc len="12"?>Resilienz sollte als ständiger Anpassungsprozess zwischen Systemen und der Umwelt begriffen werden.<? /abc ?>
>>> print uescapes.sub(uescape_decode, u'\\u003c? abc ?\\u003eDas Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von \xd6kosystemen abgeleitet.\\u003c? /abc ?\\u003e')
<? abc ?>Das Modell des Adaptiven Zyklus wurde aus vergleichenden Untersuchungen zur Dynamik von Ökosystemen abgeleitet.<? /abc ?>
```

Comment: Thank's!!! That's a good hint! But I still have troubles with json.loads: ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 57 - line 1 column 283 (char 57 

Think I have to clean up some stuff. Think your answer solves my problem. If my stuff works out I'm happy to accept it. Thank you so far.

Comment: @martin-pieters, your answer is simply correct. The problem is, that i provided a stripped down, simple version of the unicode example. With the simple version, your solution works great but it breaks with the updated one.

Comment: @hetsch: Updated with a regex approach.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: it happens to work in Python 2.7, provided you have a UCS-2 narrow build; in that case `uescapes.sub(uescape_decode, '\ud861\ude00')` produces `u'\U00028600'`.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples: on a UCS-4 build you end up with the surrogate pair as separate code units: `u'\ud861\ude00'`; encoding to UTF-16 then decoding again resolves those into their proper non-BMP codepoint.