# Converting Unicode sequences to a string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, python-3.4

In parsing an HTML response to extract data with **Python 3.4** on Kubuntu 15.10 in the Bash CLI, using `print()` I am getting output that looks like this:

```
\u05ea\u05d4 \u05e0\u05e9\u05de\u05e2 \u05de\u05e6\u05d5\u05d9\u05df
```

**How would I output the actual text itself in my application?**

This is the code generating the string:

```
response = requests.get(url)
messages = json.loads( extract_json(response.text) )

for k,v in messages.items():
    for message in v['foo']['bar']:
        print("\nFoobar: %s" % (message['body'],))
```

Here is the function which returns the JSON from the HTML page:

```
def extract_json(input_):

    """
    Get the JSON out of a webpage.
    The line of interest looks like this:
    foobar = ["{\"name\":\"dotan\",\"age\":38}"]
    """

    for line in input_.split('\n'):
        if 'foobar' in line:
            return line[line.find('"')+1:-2].replace(r'\"',r'"')

    return None
```

In googling the issue, I've found [quite a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004431/text-with-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-in-python) of [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990169/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-python-string) relating to [Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828284/conversion-of-strings-like-uxxxx-in-python), however **Python 3** has completely changed how strings and especially Unicode are handled in Python.

**How can I convert the example string (`\u05ea`) to characters (`ת`) in Python 3?**

**Addendum:**

Here is some information regarding `message['body']`:

```
print(type(message['body']))
# Prints: <class 'str'>

print(message['body'])
# Prints: \u05ea\u05d4 \u05e0\u05e9\u05de\u05e2 \u05de\u05e6\u05d5\u05d9\u05df

print(repr(message['body']))
# Prints: '\\u05ea\u05d4 \\u05e0\\u05e9\\u05de\\u05e2 \\u05de\\u05e6\\u05d5\\u05d9\\u05df'

print(message['body'].encode().decode())
# Prints: \u05ea\u05d4 \u05e0\u05e9\u05de\u05e2 \u05de\u05e6\u05d5\u05d9\u05df

print(message['body'].encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
# Prints: תה נשמע מצוין
```

Note that the last line does work as expected, but it has a few issues:

- Decoding string literals with unicode-escape is the wrong thing as Python escapes are different to JSON escapes for many characters. (Thank you [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince))
- `encode()` relies on the default encoding, which is a bad thing.(Thank you [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince))
- The `encode()` fails on some newer Unicode characters, such as [\ud83d\ude03](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f603/index.htm), with UnicodeEncodeError "surrogates not allowed".

Comment: what is `print(ascii(message['body']))`? Unrelated: use `messages = response.json()`.

Comment: If the input is not JSON then what is it? `print(response.content[:50])`; `print(response.headers['Content-Type'])`. Can you change the upstream format returned by the service?

Comment: it is not what I've asked. Run the code from the comment as is.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `b'\r\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta '` and `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Thank you.

Comment: now we are getting somewhere. Could you post *the real* code that you use to get `messages`? (between `requests.get()` and `json.loads()` including)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: **I've removed the reduced test case and posted the actual code in use.**

Comment: what happens if you run `print(u"\u05ea")` in the same environment where `print("\nFoobar:..)` is executed? What is `sys.stdout.encoding`, `sys.stdout.errors`? What is `print(ascii(line[:10]))` before `.replace(r'\"',r'"')`?  Drop `str()` around `line`.

Comment: print(u"\u05ea"): `ת` | print("\u05ea"): `ת` | sys.stdout.encoding: `UTF-8` | sys.stdout.errors: `strict` | ascii(line[:10]): `'\t\t\t\t\tfooba'` | Thank you!

Comment: increase `:10`  until you see `\u` in the output. Are you sure you are running `print(u"\u05ea")` in the *same* environment as `print("\nFoobar:..)` (to make sure add `print(u"\u05ea")` just before `print("\nFoobar:..)` in the code)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, it is the same environment. I just copied and pasted into the code file and ran it along with the other tests. Here is the output for  `print(ascii(line[350:450]))`: `'d\\" : \\"6104187972690232298\\", \\"body\\" : \\"\\\\u05e9\\\\u05dc\\\\u05d5\\\\u05dd \\\\u05dc\\\\u05d9\\\\u05d6\\\\u05d'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94128/discussion-between-dotancohen-and-j-f-sebastian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your input uses backslash as an escape character, you should unescape the text before passing it to `json`:

```
>>> foobar = '{\\"body\\": \\"\\\\u05e9\\"}'
>>> import re
>>> json_text = re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', foobar) # unescape
>>> import json
>>> print(json.loads(json_text)['body'])
ש
```

Don't use `'unicode-escape'` encoding on JSON text; it may produce different results:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_text = '["\\ud83d\\ude02"]'
>>> json.loads(json_text)
['']
>>> json_text.encode('ascii', 'strict').decode('unicode-escape') #XXX don't do it
'["\ud83d\ude02"]'
```

`'' == '\U0001F602'` is [U+1F602 (FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY)](http://codepoints.net/U+1F602).

Comment: Thank you very, very much! Your patience in getting down to the root of the problem in the comments is very much appreciated.

Comment: @dotancohen I'm not sure whether I understand the actual answer to this question. To convert a unicode sequence to its string representation, we have to use JSON? Is that it? No encode/decode niftiness to solve this?

Comment: Additionally, is this under-the-hood any different from `s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')`?

Comment: It's hard to explain in one comment what I'm aiming at, so please see [my separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425315/converting-unicode-sequence-to-string-in-python3-but-allow-paths-in-string).

Comment: @BramVanroy [reposted comment to fix typos] no. If you have a plain Unicode text already then you don't need to do anything with it. If you have a Unicode text in the JSON format then just use `result = json.loads(json_text)`. If you have a garbled input then try to fix it upstream; if you can't, use whatever is necessary to fix your particular broken input. Please, do note: `'\u2603'` and `r'\u2603'` are completely different things in Python (your question suggests that you do not see the difference).