# how to correctly save "\u**" to json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary:

```
data = {"data": "\u512b"}
```

while I dump that to json:

```
import json
print json.dumps(data)
```

I got:`{"a":"\\u512b"}`
What should I do to get exactly `{"a":"\u512b"}`?

NOTE: I try to add `u` before the string so it becomes `u'\u512b'` and the extra `\` won't show up again, please also tell me why

Comment: can you reformulate `I try to add u before the string and it works, please also tell me why`, I don't understand this sentence

Comment: also: `json.dump(data)` doesn't work, as `json.dump` expects two parameters: a object and a filepointer

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828284/conversion-of-strings-like-uxxxx-in-python

Comment: @hansaplast what you mentioned is fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do some hacking.

```
import json

data = {"data": "\u512b"}
s = json.dumps(data)
print(s.replace(r'\u', 'u'))
print(type(s.replace(r'\u', 'u')))
```

Output:

```
{"data": "\u512b"}
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are just confused by the output of the Python interpreter, displaying you the `json.dumps` generated string with its own `\` escape character prepended to the `\` character in the string. The JSON string as a value contains exactly one `\`, as you want (IIUC):

```
>>> data = {"data": "\u512b"}
>>> data
{'data': '\u512b'}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"data": "\\u512b"}'
>>> print(json.dumps(data))
{"data": "\u512b"}
>>> json.dump(data, open('data.json', 'w'))
>>> ^Z
C:\opt\Console2>type data.json
{"data": "\u512b"}
```

This is entirely independent of JSON in fact, as the following example shows:

```
>>> s = "s\\u"
>>> s
's\\u'
>>> print(s, len(s))   # length of s is 3, not 4
s\u 3
```

HTH!